# How to set instance name database in ruby configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app (ruby on rails) is in linux and I need connect in a Sql Server database.

Testing in command line I get:

```
$tsql -LH 10.10.10.10

  ServerName MYCOMPSRV10
InstanceName SQL2008R2
 IsClustered No
     Version 10.50.4000.0
         tcp 58891
```

And I can access database in command line using:

```
 $tsql -S 10.10.10.10\\SQL2008R2 -U username
```

So, in my Ruby on Rails app I have database.yml with this code:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 10.10.10.10
  database: MyDatabase
  username: username
  password: password
  port: 1433 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

But when I try run the app I get:

```
TinyTds::Error: Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
```

If I change config an try to add Database Instance Name:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: '10.10.10.10\SQL2008R2'
  database: MyDatabase
  username: username
  password: password
  port: 1433 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And try run the App:

```
TinyTds::Error: Server name not found in configuration files
```

I did a research and don't found how to solve this problem. I even don't found how to set the instance name of database.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

install:
unixodbc
unixodbc-bin
unixodbc-dev

```
  sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-bin unixodbc-dev
```

uninstall
freetds-bin
freetds-dev
freetds-common

```
sudo apt-get purge freetds-bin freetds-dev freetds-common
```

download freetds current and install:

```
tar -xzf freetds-patched.tar.gz
cd freetds-1.00.15/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I discovered the dinamic port of my db instance trough this query:

```
SELECT local_tcp_port
FROM   sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
```

and change database.yml config adding this port instead default 1433

```
development:
  <<: *default
  host: 10.10.10.10
  username: myuser
  password: mypwd
  port: 58891
```

after that I run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Everything worked fine